# I want to fetch the data of table from database by using foreach loop for php

Tags: php

I want to fetch the data of table from database by using foreach loop.
the data will be in good tabular manner for php

```
<?php
include('connection.inc.php');
include('functions.inc.php');
?>
<?php

$subcategories = getRows($con, "SELECT SUBCATEGORIES_ID, SUBCATEGORY_NAME FROM TBL_SUBCATEGORIES");
foreach($tbl_auction_bids as $value){
        echo "$value <br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: where is the c# or vb.net, why and where do you need those ?

Comment: downvote for asking no question and not using stackoverflow search or google

Answer (score 0):

what's your problem dude?
you didn't clarify it that much but as i look unto your code, 
why are you using function instead of the built-in functions in php for mysql
that should be

```
##your code Edited>>>
<?php
include('connection.inc.php');
include('functions.inc.php');
?>
<?php
// i will just show mysql_query as it seems that it fits into your code
$subcategories = mysql_query($con, 
"SELECT SUBCATEGORIES_ID,SUBCATEGORY_NAME FROM TBL_SUBCATEGORIES");
 $tbl_auction_bids = mysql_fetch_assoc($subcategories);   
 echo '<table border=1px>';
 foreach($tbl_auction_bids as $key=>$value){
    echo "<tr><td>Key:$key</td><td>Value:$value</td></tr>";
 }

 ?>
```